# How to Display an item inside my ArrayList C# console

Tags: c#, arraylist, console

Okay I'm in process to learn console by using C#. I know the basic of ArrayList which is Add and Delete but I don't know how to display the object. Here is the example of my coding that shows I add some item in my ArrayList. I want to display every details of the item by inserting an item code.

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

Console.WriteLine("\n\tADD NEW ITEM\n\nPlease enter item details");
Console.Write("Item code: ");
arr.Add = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Item description: ");
arr.Add = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Price: RM");
arr.Add = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Quantity: ");
arr.Add = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("FIND ITEM");
Console.Write("Item code: ");
```

Okay, I'm lost and have no idea by this last code of mine.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you should create a class the represents your item. Like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; } 
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Use an typed List to hold the items. It works like ArrayList, but typed. Here's the code:

```
List<Item> listOfItems = new List<Item>();
//we will create 10 items.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //instantiate the object
    Item item = new Item();
    Console.WriteLine("\n\tADD NEW ITEM\n\nPlease enter item details");
    Console.Write("Item code: ");
    item.Code = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Item description: ");
    item.Description = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Price: RM");
    item.Price = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Quantity: ");
    item.Quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    //we must add this item to our list
    listOfItems.Add(item);
}
```

To look for an item:

```
Console.WriteLine("FIND ITEM");
Console.Write("Item code: ");
int selectedCode = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

//use LINQ to search for the item
Item selectedItem = listOfItems.Where(i => i.Code == selectedCode).FirstOrDefault();

//check if an item was found
if (selectedItem != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Item found!");
   //print the item
   Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}", selectedItem.Code);
   Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", selectedItem.Description);
   Console.WriteLine("Price: {0}", selectedItem.Price.ToString("c"));
   Console.WriteLine("Quanitty: {0}", selectedItem.Quantity);
}
```

Untested code but should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your array with foreach?

```
foreach ( Object obj in arr )
      Console.Write( "{0}", obj );
      Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @RPradeep . I know how to show everything. I just want to display an item based on their item code.

Comment: Hey@AbbasShafiq. I think your requirements and the way you are using are wrong. What you can do is , you can create a new Class with Code,Description and Price as Item.
And add new items to your list.
And then use contains method to check if your list contains that item

Answer (score 0):

Here you are adding each item property as an element into arraylist. Instead Create a class which has all item properties and then add back to array list. then we can filter search through array list.

```
static class  Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList mainList = new ArrayList();

        string enterMore="yes";
        while (enterMore == "yes" || enterMore == "YES")
        {
            ItemObject item = new ItemObject();
            Console.Write("Item code: ");
            item.itemCode = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Item description: ");
            item.description = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Price: RM");
            item.price = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Quantity: ");
            item.quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            mainList.Add(item);

            Console.Write("{Type 'yes' to enter more} Want to enter more?");
            enterMore = Console.ReadLine();

        }



        string searchMore = "yes";
        while (searchMore == "yes" || searchMore == "YES")
        {

            Console.Write("Enter item code to SEARCH?  ");
            string itemCode = Console.ReadLine();

            //Arraylist stores evarything as an object type. so we are casting object into itemObject
            ArrayList searchResults = new ArrayList(mainList.Cast<ItemObject>()
                                             .Where(d => d.itemCode == itemCode)
                                             .ToList());


            Console.Write("Search Results: ");
            foreach(Object item in searchResults){
                ItemObject obj = (ItemObject)item;
                Console.WriteLine(obj.itemCode);
                Console.WriteLine(obj.description);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.Write("{Type 'yes' to search more} Want to search more?");
            searchMore = Console.ReadLine();

        }



    }

}
class ItemObject
{
    public string itemCode { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public float quantity { get; set; }
}
```